# Flowable не реагирует на отсутствие элемента в БД Room

Tags: java, android, android-room, rxjava2

В [этой](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/room-rxjava-acb0cd4f3757) статье написано:

> Here’s how the Flowable/Observable behaves:
>
> When there is no user in the database and the query returns no rows,
>   the Flowable will not emit, neither onNext, nor onError.
>
> When there is a user in the database, the Flowable will trigger
>   onNext.
>
> Every time the user data is updated, the Flowable object will emit
>   automatically, allowing you to update the UI based on the latest data.

Мне нужно, чтобы Flowable мог показать, что в БД нет заданного элемента(ов), например, дёргал onError, отправляя туда специальный Throwable.

Каким способом этого можно добиться?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вопрос в том что именно вам нужно.

1. Если вам нужны уведомления об изменениях в таблице + ошибка, если данных нет, то надо вручную эту ситуацию обрабатывать, например, так: получаем данные единожды и, если они есть, заменяем источник на Flowable, который будет уведомления об изменениях выдавать.

   код на [kotlin](/questions/tagged/kotlin) + либа [RxKotlin](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxKotlin)

   ```
   getDataAsSingle()
       .flatMap{ getDataAsFlowable() }
       .subscribeBy(
           onNext = { /** тут будут обновления данных **/ },
           onError = { /** тут будет EmptyResultSetException если данных в таблице нет **/ }
       )
   ```
2. Если получить один раз данные или выкинуть ошибку, если их нет, то просто используйте Single:

   код на [kotlin](/questions/tagged/kotlin) + либа [RxKotlin](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxKotlin)

   ```
   getDataAsSingle()
       .subscribeBy(
           onSuccess = { /** тут будут данные из БД **/ },
           onError = { /** тут будет EmptyResultSetException если данных в таблице нет **/ }
       )
   ```

Comment: Разве в первом варианте не должен быть метод flatMapPublisher?

Comment: @timuruktus, не очень понимаю о чём вы) Про publisher ничего не знаю.